# Boolean value inside OnResponse Android Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm new to android and I have a problem trying to return a boolean value depending on the response inside OnResponse for Android Volley. Whenever the json response from OnResponse equals a certain value I want to return a boolean value, however while I tried doing that I realized that the boolean value wasn't set on according to the code (possibly because of threads.). This is where I would like to integrate it:

```
 final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, key, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                      //here I obtain the json object and based on it I want to make the boolean false or true

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 404) {

                  ....
                }
            }


        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
     
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            
        };
        mRequestQueue.add(request);

        return boolean;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Answer (score 0):

When you write networking codes (in this case, using volley), your codes don't get executed sequencially. That is, when you make a network call, the response may come after, say 2 seconds. So these codes are asynchronous. In these cases, we use callbacks.
I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
boolean result = getNetworkResult(); // suppose, your code is inside getNetworkResult() method
if(result == true) {
 Log.e(TAG, "Do something on success");
}else{
 Log.e(TAG, "Do something on failure");
}
```

Since your given code is asynchronous, it won't work like this way. That's why we use callbacks / listeners. So, your code would look something like this:

```
 final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, key, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                      //here I obtain the json object and based on it I want to make the boolean false or true
                    // just simply write your logic inside here
                    boolean result; // your conditions
                    if(result == true) {
                       Log.e(TAG, "Do something on success");   // <----- Look here
                   }else{
                       Log.e(TAG, "Do something on failure"); // <----- Look here
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 404) {

                  ....
                }
            }


        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
     
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            
        };
        mRequestQueue.add(request);

        //  return boolean;  // <-- this won't work, so I am commenting it out
    }
```

Now, if you really want to write code that 'looks' like sequential (but behind the hood it is actually asynchronous), then you could try kotlin coroutine. I found this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53486222/9053942), which shows how to use coroutine with volley. Please check it out.

### Edit

Based on your comment, I think you should write your code in this way:
Suppose you have 2 activities: `MainActivity`, and `DetailsActivity`. Instead of keeping a boolean variable inside `MainActivity`, try passing a boolean value to `DetailsActivity`.

So the code can look like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   
    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, key, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                      // the new logic

                      if(response.toString().contains("farewall to arms")) {
                        // open new activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("YOUR_BOOLEAN_VALUE", true);  // Here we are passing the boolean result
        intent.putExtra("SOME_STRING", response.toString());
        // pass more variables that you need...
        startActivityForResult(intent, 8080);
                      }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 404) {

                  ....
                }
            }


        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            }

            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        };
        mRequestQueue.add(request);

        //  return boolean;  // <-- this won't work, so I am commenting it out
    }

  }
}
```

Now inside `DetailsActivity`:

```java
class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("YOUR_BOOLEAN_VALUE");
String yourResponse = getIntent().getExtras().getString("SOME_STRING");

         // now inside your for loop
         for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if(yourBool == true) { break;}
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still have some questions since I can't see how I could solve the problem I have using this: inside on response :  if ((checkSimilarity(jsonObj.getString('title')) < 20)
                                                    {  result=true; } and this onresponse from jsonrequest is inside of another function, but I can't seem to get the boolean inside the function, whilst inside onresponse it works correctly.

Comment: The boolean inside the function won't work. But if you create a boolean variable in your class, then you can access that boolean variable. That is `class YourActivity{ private boolean someBool; /*you should be able to access this*/  } `. By the way, could you tell me what you are actually trying to do? Perhaps reorganizing your logic will be a good idea.

Comment: I tried also adding the boolean to the class but I guess since it's asynchronous, threads 
 mess with the boolean and don't show the right value at the right time. Well each time the json object's has some properties im looking for then I am setting a boolean to true, and storing that json object while opening another activity with details about the object. For example each time the title of the json object is "farewall to arms" for example, im keeping that book and opening details about it and also settig the boolean to true. I need the boolean because I have a for in another activity that

Comment: ... calls the function with the volley call but with a different key string from a list of strings. If the book with the string was found by volley call (boolean is true), then i want to break from the for as so: (String key:listOfString) { if( parseJSONObject()){ break; }   }

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it and let me know.

Comment: Still doesn't help much, tried it not working, however I implemented a new logic but because of the asynchronous nature still having problem since the for is not completed and Log.v which shows the size is 0 although at the end the array is size 16:

Comment: for (String author : textFromBlocksMerged){

            mBooks = new ArrayList<>();
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            Log.v("BOOKAPI", "author:" + author);
            if (author == null) {

                Log.v("BOOKAPI", "NULL author");
            }
            mBooks.clear();
            boolean isFound = searchByAuthor(author, textFromBlocksMerged);
            Log.v("wazfound",isFound+"in search by author");}
        Log.v("book", "-------------all books size at end---------" + String.valueOf(allBooks.size()));

Comment: do you use github or something similar? maybe I can have a look into your project and tell you what went wrong.